# Seeing last frame from previous session of camera usage on iOS application made with Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, camera, ios-camera

I have an **iOS** application made with **Xamarin Forms** in C#. I use **CortexDecoderUnifiedXF** (version 3.8.0) to scan barcodes. When i open the page with camera preview the first time, everything is working fine. When i open the page with camera preview the second time, for like 100ms i see the frame of the previous session and then it continues to show real time camera capture. This happened also in other project i worked on and with different NuGet packages that used camera and on different iOS version and different iPhone models.

Question: is there a way to avoid seeing last frame of the previous camera using session when i launch the camera again? How can it be done?

Possible-solution questions:
Is hiding the camera preview for some time would be the only option? And how much time to wait?
Or it is possible to clear camera buffer (or what is that called) when the page is opening so that there is no last-camera-frame saved?

Tried to show the camera preview as soon as the page is ready after navigation but it doesn't help.